# Firebase Cloud Functions not returning Promise and never stop calling

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const ref = admin.database().ref()


    exports.updateActiveUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
                console.log("updateActiveUsers Called")

                const currentTime = new Date().getTime()
                const startDate = currentTime - 432000000
                var allPromises = []
             return ref.child('users').orderByChild('lastOnline').once('value').then(snap =>{

                    snap.forEach(childSnap => {
                        console.log(childSnap.val().userID)
                        if (childSnap.val().lastOnline > startDate){
                            const ref2 = ref.child("activeUsers/" +  childSnap.val().userID).set(true)
                            allPromises.push(ref2)
                        }else{
                            const ref2 = ref.child("activeUsers/" +  childSnap.val().userID).remove()
                            allPromises.push(ref2)
                        }

                    })
                    console.log("promises: " + allPromises)
                    return Promise.all(allPromises)

                })
            })
```

I cannot seem to make it return or end the function. I go the the http url it provides when uploading, it works, but the page keeps loading and I look at the logs, and the function keeps being called when it finishes. Clearly the Promise is not being returned properly, and I am not sure why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing the changes for each user individually, you can update them all at once.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const usersRef = admin.database().ref('users');
const lastOnlineQuery = usersRef.orderByChild('lastOnline');

exports.updateActiveUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  const startDate = currentTime - 432000000;

  let values = {};
  let activeCount = 0;

  return lastOnlineQuery.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      let { lastOnline, userID } = child.val();
      let value = lastOnline > startDate || null;
      values[`activeUsers/${userID}`] = value;
      activeCount += value;
    });
    return admin.database().ref().update(values);
  }).then(() => {
    res.send(`Active users: ${activeCount}`);
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(500);
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this still hasn't fixed the problem. The function keeps calling and the webpage never finishes loading as before. Could there be another reason as to why this is?

Comment: Ah it's because you're supposed to return a response using `res` – the page never renders because you don't send a response.

Comment: Thank you so much!